# How to add an attribute to an attribute set in magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I have only the attribute code, and II want to add it into the default attribute set, at the bottom of the general group.

I've read many other posts but they're all creating the attribute at the same time

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to `Catalog->Attribute->Manage Attribute Sets` from the admin panel, edit default attribute set and add your attribute by dragging and dropping it to the general tab.